# how to show top keywords and most popular page with gapi

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

With Google Analytics API how can I show top keywords for a specific month or how about like the top 5 most viewed pages for a specific month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you replace YOUR_GOOGLE_ID with the correct ID ( e.g. ga-XXXXXX ) of your Google Analytics account. You should also change the start-date and end-date to match the specific month you are targeting.

Keywords

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3AYOUR_GOOGLE_ID4&dimensions=ga%3Akeyword&metrics=ga%3Avisits&sort=-ga%3Avisits&start-date=2011-10-1&end-date=2011-10-31&max-results=50
```

Top5 Pages

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3AYOUR_GOOGLE_ID&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews%2Cga%3AtimeOnPage%2Cga%3Abounces%2Cga%3Aentrances%2Cga%3Aexits&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&start-date=2011-10-1&end-date=2011-10-31&max-results=5
```

See http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataCommonQueries.html for more examples

Comment: Exactly. In the link they point to the Data Feed Query Explorer which is an excellent place to start for questions like this: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html